RestClientTest exclude repository beans in test
I'm trying to test my RestClient service.
However when I execute the test I get
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRepository' defined in org.app.domain.account.AccountRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on Application: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.mapping.JdbcMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'
Seems like it autoconfigure repository beans despide documentations of (@RestClientTest) says it disables full auto-configuration.
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@RestClientTest(value = {AccountServiceClient.class})
public class AccountServiceClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private AccountServiceClient serviceClient;

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Test
    void testLoginFail() {
        // stuff

        assertThatCode(() -> mockServer.verify()).doesNotThrowAnyException();
    }
}

@EnableCaching
@EnableJdbcRepositories(basePackages = "org.app.domain")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "org.app")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

I've tried to add in RestClientTest but didn't work:
excludeAutoConfiguration = {
DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, 
JdbcClientAutoConfiguration.class,
JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.class
})
Is there a solution that exclude all repositories automatically instead of using @MockBean for each repo?
---- update after suggestion
I created a new configuration class and it worked
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories(basePackages ="org.app.domain")
public class RepositoryConfig {}


The problem is that you added @EnableJdbcRepositories to the @SpringBootApplication class, which prevents @RestClientTest to disable it as it is now forcefully included. Move those @Enable annotations to a seperate @Configuration class and they will be ignored. Or remove it all together, as your Application class should be in org.app to start with and that would automatically scan that pacakage and enable JDBC repositories.

I managed to externalize configuration as you did and it worked
Thank you
